# How to avoid segmentation fault in recursive function with strings in C?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, segmentation-fault, cs50

**Note:** *I am not trying to get the algorithmic implementation!  I already have it figured out in Java.  I just can't seem to get my logic to work in C. Below is the Java code (which works) followed by the C99 code that breaks.*

The high-level coding challenge that is presenting the segfault in my implementation is:

> How to find all combinations of k length and smaller using alphabet of length n **with repeating elements** in **C**?

#### Problem

Code compiles, but I get a segmentation fault at runtime.

#### Notes / Observations

- This is from a self-paced edX course I'm working my way through.  I've already done the "less comfortable" challenges, and frankly they were a bit too easy.  I'm now trying to go above the requirements and do this "more comfortable" (read more challenging) challenge.  It is one of the more advanced beginner challenges.
- I'm not a beginner programmer, but pretty much a novice with C.
- As far as I understand it, the `<cs50.h>`is a custom header file that implements some things that simplify (read abstract away) command-line input and handling of strings. Documentation in it can be found at [the cs50.net site](https://reference.cs50.net/) and on the [cs50lib GitHub page](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50)
- I can't figure out the correct way to pass the values to the recursive function and need to utilize address referencing/dereferencing.  Unfortunately my C is a bit fuzzy compared to other langs.

#### Test Calls with Desired Output Result

```
~/myTerminal $ ./printall ab 3
aaa
aab
aba
abb
baa
bab
bba
bbb
aa
ab
ba
bb
a
b
~/myTerminal $ ./printall abc 2
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
a
b
c
myTerminal $ ./printall abcd 1
a
b
c
d
```

#### Java Code that Works

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("First Test");
        char[] set1 = {'a', 'b'};
        int k = 3;
        printCombinations(set1, k);

        System.out.println("\nSecond Test");
        char[] set2 = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        k = 2;
        printCombinations(set2, k);

        System.out.println("\nThird Test");
        char[] set3 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
        k = 1;
        printCombinations(set3, k);
    }

// Print all possible strings of length k or smaller.
    static void printCombinations(char[] set, int k) {
        int n = set.length;
        for(int i = k; i > 0; i--)
        {
            printCombinationsRec(set, "", n, i);
        }

    }

// Print all combinations of length k
    static void printCombinationsRec(char[] set, String prefix, int n, int k)
    {
        if (k == 0)
        { // Base case
            System.out.println(prefix);
            return;
        }

        // One by one add all characters
        // from set and recursively
        // call for k equals to k-1
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            String newPrefix = prefix + set[i];
            printCombinationsRec(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

#### C Code Causing Segmentation Fault

```
// CS50 custom header file
#include <cs50.h>
// "Regular" headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printCombinations();
void printCombinationsRecur();
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 3) // Correct number of arguments
    {
        string strSet = argv[1];
        int maxLength = atoi(argv[2]);
        printCombinations(strSet, maxLength);
        return 0;
    }
    // Incorrect usage
    printf("Usage: %s <charset>:string\n <maxLength>:int\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}

// Functions below were adapted and modified from code at :
// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-given-length/
// Accessed : 2018-07-13
void printCombinations(string sSet, int strLength)
{
    int aLength = strlen(sSet);
    for (int i = strLength; i > 0; i--)
    {
        printCombinationsRecur(sSet, "", aLength, strLength);
    }
}

void printCombinationsRecur(string *sSet, string prefix, int aLength, int strLength )
{
    // printf("sSet: %s\nprefix: %s\naLength: %i\nstrLength: %i\n", *sSet, prefix, aLength, strLength);
    // In terms of the traditional equation k=> strLength, n=>aLength, S=>sSet

    if (strLength == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", prefix);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < aLength; i++)
    {
        string temp1 = "";
        strcat(temp1, prefix); // <== SEGFAULT HAPPENING HERE!
        string newPrefix = strcat(temp1, sSet[i]);
        printCombinationsRecur(sSet, newPrefix, aLength, strLength - 1);
    }
}
```

I made the following change (suggested by @Stargateur) to the recursive function, but still get a segfault!

```
    void printCombinationsRecur(string *sSet, string prefix, int aLength, int strLength )
{
    // printf("sSet: %s\nprefix: %s\naLength: %i\nstrLength: %i\n", *sSet, prefix, aLength, strLength);
    // In terms of the traditional equation k=> strLength, n=>aLength, S=>sSet

    if (strLength == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", prefix);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < aLength; i++)
    {
        printf("This prints");
        char  *temp1 = malloc((strLength +2) * sizeof(char));
        for (int j = 0; j < strLength + 2; j++){
            if(j < strLength)
            {
                temp1[j] = prefix[j];
            }
            if(j == strLength)
            {
                temp1[j] = *sSet[i];
            }
            if(j == strLength + 1){
                temp1[j] = '\0';
            }
        }

        printCombinationsRecur(sSet, temp1, aLength, strLength - 1);
        free(temp1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to open a debate, but cs50 would not be my choice to learn C. First problem is typedef `string` hiding pointer, this is pure evil. I advise you to stop this non sense and write the true type `char *`.

Comment: `string` in your C code is almost certainly a `char *`, which is significantly different from a Java `String`.

Comment: You know, the CS50x IDE has a great debugger built in. Learning how to use it is part of the course, so you really should be using that first instead of dumping code in here.

Comment: @Stargateur - I agree with your reasoning, but can you elaborate specifically how you might make that change?  Like I said, I'm a C novice, not a programming novice.  Any constructive comments are greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage - Thanks.  I'm well aware of the debugger and the IDE's benefits.  I've been using command-line for quite some time before heading into the CS50 thing.  As far as "dumping code", I don't think you can reasonably say that's what I'm doing.  I'm asking an honest question to aid my understanding.  Thanks.

Comment: @jxh - Yes, I know the "canonical" way of doing it is with a *char, but I'm asking for someone to show me how that will work in the recursive function.  Thanks.

Comment: `string temp1 = "";` this doesn't create a "dynamic" string. You write `char * temp1 = ""`, attempt to write more than 1 `char` on it would lead to undefined behavior. And attempt to modify the only one byte of this string is implemented behavior and spoiler most compiler tell you it's undefined behavior. You need to allocate somehow space for your string (with `char *temp1= malloc(SIZE_MAX);` or automatic storage like `char temp1[SIZE_MAX];`)

Comment: @jxh - no teacher!  Self-paced!  I know the difference between the C char and a Java string.

Comment: @Stargateur is that what you are talking about?  ... in the edit I made?

Comment: It doesn't really make a difference in this case (because `sizeof(char)` is 1), but `strLength +1 * sizeof(char)` should be `(strLength +1) * sizeof(char)`.

Comment: @Barmar hey thanks for pointing out that typo.  My bad, I've changed it.

Comment: This is suspicious: `temp1[j] = *sSet[i];` This is done when `j = strLength`, but that element should contain the trailing null byte.

Comment: I give you a [hint](http://rextester.com/VVHKX42376)

Comment: @Barmar strikes again!  I'll edit that.  Totally forgot to put the null byte, but that still doesn't get me over the segfault.  Thanks.

Comment: @Stargateur Tried to run it on rextester, but came back with the following error:
    source_file.c:33:28: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *' to 
    parameter of type 'char **'; take the address with & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        printCombinationsRecur(sSet, "", aLength, strLength);
                           ^~~~
                           &
source_file.c:5:43: note: passing argument to parameter 'sSet' here
static void printCombinationsRecur(char **sSet, char *prefix, size_t aLength,
                                          ^
1 warning generated.

Comment: @tyj247 this is the hint. you should have similar warning on your machine when you compile. That not your only error, but try to understand it before fix your algo

Comment: @Stargateur - will do.  I think I'm just losing it on the mechanics of pointing and dereferencing.

Comment: @Stargateur - what's with the double pointer on the sSet arg to the recursive function?  And the error I get suggests the dereferencing operator. |~

Comment: LOL @Stargateur . I wan't the solution, but more importantly I wan't to understand.  Not just fishing for pat answers.  Thanks.  I'll save that link for when I'm on my 20th cup of coffee. ;)

Comment: forget the last version..., when you get tired here a more correct [solution](http://rextester.com/XHJZ95888), sometime an correct exemple learn you more than try and error.

Comment: An important first step is to figure out what line is causing the segmentation fault and what the pointer being dereferenced is.  Running in a debugger should tell you that, but it's also a good idea to pepper the code with assertions that your array indices are in bounds and your pointers are not null pointers.

Comment: However, I think @tyj247 got it.  You’re calling `printCombinationsRecur(sSet, newPrefix, aLength, strLength - 1)`, where the first argument is a “string,” but the type of that parameter is a “string*” and you dereference it twice. So, you’re interpreting bytes of the string as a garbage pointer. That shouldn’t even compile—if it does, you need to turn on a lot more warnings in your compiler.

Comment: There might well be other bugs than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the key differences between your Java code that works and the C code that doesn't is in the `printCombinations()` function.

**Working Java:**

```
for(int i = k; i > 0; i--)
{
    printCombinationsRec(set, "", n, i);
}
```

**Broken C:**

```
int aLength = strlen(sSet);
for (int i = strLength; i > 0; i--)
{
    printCombinationsRecur(sSet, "", aLength, strLength);
}
```

You're calling the recursive function with the same length, over and over and over again.  To match the Java, the `strLength` argument should be `i` instead.

You also do not handle the base case properly.  The Java code returns after printing if `k == 0`; the C code doesn't.

**Working Java:**

```
if (k == 0)
{ // Base case
    System.out.println(prefix);
    return;
}
```

**Broken C:**

```
if (strLength == 0)
{
    printf("%s\n", prefix);
}
```

And then you handle the string concatenation incorrectly.  C is not very forgiving.  There are at least two ways to handle it.  The method that will work with any version of C uses `malloc()`.  The method that will work with C99, or with C11 as long as the compiler does not define `__STDC_NO_VLA__`, uses a VLA.  The version using `malloc()` also calls `free()` and so it does a bit more work than the other.

Since the length allocated is always the same, you could offset the cost by calling `malloc()` once before the loop and `free()` once after the loop, and you'd only need to copy the prefix once and then simply set the extra characters (even the null could be set once).  You could also enhance the VLA code to define the new prefix array once outside the loop, copy the prefix once, set the null byte once, and just set the extra character inside the loop.

You should also use formal prototype declarations for the functions, not mere function declarations that care not one whit about the arguments presented.

The code shown below is lazy and does not check that the `malloc()` calls work.  It also does not validate that the alphabet is a sensible length, nor that the maximum length is reasonable, nor that the elements in the alphabet are unique.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void printCombinations(const char *set, int strLength);
static void printCombinationsRec(const char *set, const char *prefix, int aLength, int strLength);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s alphabet maxlen\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    /* GIGO: garbage in, garbage out */
    char *strSet = argv[1];
    int maxLength = atoi(argv[2]);
    printCombinations(strSet, maxLength);
    return 0;
}

static void printCombinations(const char *set, int k)
{
    int n = strlen(set);
    for (int i = k; i > 0; i--)
    {
        printCombinationsRec(set, "", n, i);
    }
}

#if defined(USE_VLA) && __STDC_NO_VLA__ != 1

static void printCombinationsRec(const char *set, const char *prefix, int n, int k)
{
    if (k == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", prefix);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(prefix);
        char newPrefix[len + 2];
        strcpy(newPrefix, prefix);
        newPrefix[len + 0] = set[i];
        newPrefix[len + 1] = '\0';
        printCombinationsRec(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1);
    }
}

#else

static void printCombinationsRec(const char *set, const char *prefix, int n, int k)
{
    if (k == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", prefix);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(prefix);
        char *newPrefix = malloc(len + 2);
        strcpy(newPrefix, prefix);
        newPrefix[len + 0] = set[i];
        newPrefix[len + 1] = '\0';
        printCombinationsRec(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1);
        free(newPrefix);
    }
}

#endif /* USE_VLA */
```

Compiled with `-DUSE_VLA` with a compiler that supports VLAs, it will not use `malloc()`.  Compiled without the option, or with a compiler that supports C11 but does not support VLAs, then it uses `malloc()` and `free()`.

At one point, I also added argument validation code in `main()`, but the 20 lines or so seemed to be more getting in the way than useful, so I left the `GIGO` comment there instead.

If this was 'production code', I'd be using error reporting functions and would not skip the checks (in part because the error reporting functions make it easier, using a single line per reported error instead of 5 or so without.  I'd be using the error reporting code available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

Note that you can't use `strcat()` easily because you want to append a single character, not a string.  Hence the use of the two assignments.  The `+ 0` emphasizes the similarity between the two assignments; the compiler does not generate any code for `+ 0`.

When run (I called it `comb47.c`, compiled to `comb47`), it produces the output desired:

```
$ comb47 ab 3
aaa
aab
aba
abb
baa
bab
bba
bbb
aa
ab
ba
bb
a
b
$ comb47 abc 2
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
a
b
c
$ comb47 abcd 1
a
b
c
d
$
```

Comment: Hey, really, thank you for the full treatment and discussion of my errors.  I will spend some time thinking over it.  Big thank you.